# Grinder how to use grinder API in java application?

Tags: grinder

I'm projecting a Java application in which, i would like to pilot the tool the grinder to do the following operation:

Start the console.
Start the test scripts.
Execute the tests.
get the report.

Someone can suggest to me where i can find usefull information to achive my objective?

Thank's a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

For automation like this there are 3 basic steps :-

1. Record
2. Modify as per your needs
3. Execute

---

- To record you will need to run grinder proxy tool.
- The recorded scripts are very specific and has lot of extra calls you need to modify them as per your needs here a tool like pydev http://pydev.org/  comes handy.
- Now you can execute the script on grinder.

For details refer to http://grinder.sourceforge.net/  everything is here.